# Multiple edits without any changes

Tags: support, suggested-edits

could someone please help me out, why these guys get edits for [a change](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20020219/revisions) that was done by me:

1. where nothing was changed? (mhitza)
2. where only my changes were accepted? (psxls)

Please don't get me wrong - i'm not interested in the reputation, but just curious why edits with no changes are even allowed.

Comment: It's all explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3709877). There is a edit race condition on the suggested edit where both users fix the same typo.

Comment: @Antony no race condition here, they both just clicked "Improve".

Comment: @ShadowWizard Maybe I should be careful with my terms. I mean they perform identical actions reviewing the suggested edit at almost the same time.

Comment: @ben nope, 843 is less than 2K last I checked :)

Comment: If you think this is a problem, you should tag it with [meta-tag:bug], but as Antony and Shadow have said, it's not a bug.

Comment: Oops, was looking at the two people who edited, not at the suggester @Sha.

Comment: what did they improve, when there were no changes? I still don't get it...

Comment: To sum this up, look in the faq under "Sometimes the Community user approves or rejects my edit. What does that mean?" to learn what happened here. [You got the +2 rep just fine by the way](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lIQm0.png).

Comment: thanks @ShadowWizard, the faq finally helped me understand

Comment: @erndenson you made "doucmentation" a link, but this word is typo in English. Two reviewers noticed that and chose to improve by changing it to the correct word. (documentation) :)

Comment: jep - that's the "Change" :D

Comment: Not even a dupe, just a 'too localized', misunderstanding problem.